# Printing a web page as a pdf to show all the css styles

Tags: css, pdf, printing, html

I created a button (printerFriendly) that opens a new tab with sections of my webpage that I want to print.  3 Sections specifically.

The table has css applied to it that shows certain aspects of the table with different colors depending on the data and I want that color to be shown when printed.  In this new tab, I do a print preview, and I see the sections of the page on top of each other.  There is no spacing between the sections.  I was looking into the solution and I believe one way would be to have the page to print as a pdf.
It told me to add media="print" to index.html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" media="print">
```

But this expands the navigation and data selection for the table of the main page and looks bad.

I want the page to print as a pdf and I want the css color styles for each section to print as well.

Here is the css I have applied so far so it can print:

```
@media print {

    body *{
        font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
        font-size: 12px;
        font-weight: 500;
        color: #101010;
        background: #f6f5fa;
        visibility: hidden;
    }
  #section-to-print, #section-to-print *{
    visibility: visible;
  }
  #section-to-print {
    position:absolute; 
    left:0;
    top:0;
  }

   #section-to-print2, #section-to-print2 *{
    visibility: visible;
  }
  #section-to-print2 {
    position:absolute; 
    left:0;
    top:0;
  }

/*
  #section-to-print3, #section-to-print3 *{
    visibility: visible;
  }
  #section-to-print3 {
    position:absolute; 
    left:0;
    top:0;
  }
*/

}
```

I have #section-to-print3 commented out because this is the third section I want to be printed, but when I apply this css, it is the only section that shows when I do a print preview and the other two are no where to be found.

Any help of tips would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Your 'secion-to-print' css rules all say `position:absolute;left:0;top:0` . So any text/stuff with that class will print on top of each other. Only the top one will be visible on screen or printed.

Remove those three statements from those rules. Then the items will print in order.

You could put a page break between each section with a `page-break-before:always` in each rule.

This page has good info on various printing CSS rules: https://www.noupe.com/design/css-perfect-print-stylesheet-98272.html